# jenkins dsl in single line doesn't work

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

Need help on understanding the Jenkins DSL formatting and how it can affect the job creation/ execution

Lets take an example of the below DSL script

```
job('readyForIntegration'){ displayName('Good For Integration Testing') 
parameters{ stringParam('param1') } }
```

If I have a job with the above text, the job fails with error "Processing provided DSL script
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method parameters() on null object".

But if I write the same script with below indentation/ formatting the job works

```
job('readyForIntegration'){ 
 displayName('Good For Integration Testing') 
 parameters{ 
  stringParam('param1') 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more to do with Groovy. In Groovy we can leave out semicolons at the end of the line as long as we use one statement per line. If we use multiple statements on a line we must use a semicolon to separate the statements.

Hence, if you want your code to be in a single line, you should do

```
job('readyForIntegration'){displayName('Good For Integration Testing') ;parameters{ stringParam('param1') } }
```